Liquibase error Incorrect syntax near INT variable decleration
I'm getting the following error from a simple SQL tag in the XML file:
Error

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Incorrect syntax near 'INT'.
[Failed SQL: (102) begin
DECLARE @MyVariable INT]

Code:
<changeSet  author="me"  id="poc" runAlways="true" runOnChange="true" >
    <sql>
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @MyVariable INT;
        SET @MyVariable = 10;
     END;
    </sql>
</changeSet>

SQL code block runs on a SQL Server 2019 with no issue.
I removed the semicolon as suggested in one of stackoverflow threads, it didn't help.

i have a feeling liquidbase does some sort of batch splitting based on ; which is wrong, probably you didn't configure it properly for sql server specific dialect

You can try splitStatements="false" perhaps, or use GO as end delimiter

The issue was resolved by adding the attribute splitStatements="true" to the SQL tag. Thanks to @siggemannen for the helpful tip.
Updated code
<changeSet author="me" id="poc" runAlways="true" runOnChange="true" >
 <sql splitStatements="true">
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @MyVariable INT;
      SET @MyVariable = 10;
  END;
 </sql>
</changeSet>

